# How to constrain regression coefficient of two variables to have opposite sign?

Tags: regression, optimization, constrained-regression

I am running a simple linear regression with a few variables but the meanings of the variables are such that certain pairs of variables should have coefficients with opposite signs. How should I specify the constraint?

Comment: Could you explain why they need to have opposite signs?  That might give some insight into how to proceed. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The factors are suppose to have opposite signs due to their meanings - they are opposite forces that contributes to the dependent variable. And if I regress them without constraint, the coefficients do have negative correlations. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I sense that you don't want to tell us much about your data. $\qquad$

Comment: assuming that the reason the sign is unexpected is because of correlation between the variables, you might find that L2 regularisation/ridge regression will resolve this.

Answer (score 7):

What you propose seems either dangerous or unnecessary.

Even if, on some theoretical basis, the 2 predictor variables have influences in different directions on the outcome variable, it's not necessarily the case that they will have opposite effects in the linear approximation that underlies the regression, particularly if there are other predictor variables involved. Forcing the coefficients to have opposite signs is making the very strong (and potentially dangerous) assumption that their opposing effects hold specifically in the linear model.

But if that is the case, then the regression should give you opposite signs for their coefficients anyway--as it apparently did. In that case the regression demonstrates directly your assumption about their opposing influences, and no one can complain that your results turned out that way because you forced them to.

So I'd recommend just sticking with the unconstrained regression.

Comment: My reaction entirely. If the coefficients genuinely have different signs, you don't need the constraint. If you apply the constraint, how do we know whether it would have been satisfied in any case? In statistics as in diplomacy, force is the last resort adopted with extreme reluctance.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Thinking about it now it does sound like too strong an assumption. Especially when there are other variables, the meaning of those two factors can not be interpreted as their standalone meanings.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a straightforward, if inelegant, way of achieving this.

Let's say that the 2 parameters in question, i.e., those constrained to have opposite sign, are $a$ and $b$. Use a bound (or linearly constrained) least squares routine to solve two different problems, then pick the solution of those two which has the lowest sum of squared residuals.

Problem 1: Constrain $a \ge 0, b \le 0$, and all other parameters unconstrained.

Problem 2: Constrain $a \le 0, b \ge 0$, and all other parameters unconstrained.

Problems having a large number of such constraints, and even more complicated relationships among the parameters, could be solved systematically using a mixed integer (quadratic programming or second order cone problem) solver to impose the needed constraints without resorting to multiple problem solves.

**EDIT:** I don't disagree with the statements from @EdM and others regarding the need for judiciousness in deciding whether to impose constraints. I have merely stated how to do so if their imposition is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like a good way to avoid turning the problem into a QCQP problem.